# Terraform erroring waiting for ECS cluster

Tags: terraform, amazon-ecs, terraform-provider-aws

I am using terraform to create an ECS cluster in AWS.

```
resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "cluster" {
  name               = "api-cluster"
  capacity_providers = ["FARGATE"]

  default_capacity_provider_strategy {
    capacity_provider = "FARGATE"
    weight            = "100"
  }
}
```

Whenever I run this code it starts fine, but then errors waiting for the cluster to be created.

```
Terraform v1.0.0
on linux_amd64
Initializing plugins and modules...
aws_ecs_cluster.cluster: Creating...
aws_ecs_cluster.cluster: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
╷
│ Error: error waiting for ECS Cluster (arn:aws:ecs:xxxxxxxxxxx:cluster/api-cluster) to become Available: couldn't find resource
│ 
│   with aws_ecs_cluster.cluster,
│   on main.tf line 73, in resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "cluster":
│   73: resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "cluster" {
│ 
╵
```

The ECS cluster is ultimately deployed, but the script errors. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's only waiting 10 seconds? That does not sound like default behavior. Do you have some sort of wait period override configured somewhere?

Comment: @MarkB - none at all. I have other scripts I run in the same way that wait >90s for CloudFront distros, etc..

I am running via Terraform Cloud if that is relevant.

Comment: Then that's... confusing. That specific code path waits for a non configurable 10 minutes until the API shows it is in the `ACTIVE` state. Just to check the IAM user/role that's being used here has the IAM permissions to describe the cluster right?

Comment: Have you trimmed that error message in any way?

Comment: In addition, you might want to verify you are using the latest version of the AWS provider.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR I'll try it with admin in the morning and see if that makes a difference. I've not trimmed that error at all.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR you were right. I was missing `ecs:DescribeClusters`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out this is caused by needing the `ecs:DescribeClusters` Action to be allowed on the user executing `terraform apply`.

Thanks to [@ydaetskocR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2291321/ydaetskcor) for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had:

```
resource "aws_ecs_cluster" "cluster" {
  name = "${var.service}-${var.env}"
}

module "ecs_service" {
   source       = "app.terraform.io/ifit/ecs-service/aws"
   version      = "2.3.0"
   cluster_name = aws_ecs_cluster.cluster.name
   ...other stuff...
}
```

It was trying to create both the ecs cluster and the ecs service at the same time, but the service depends on the cluster for the `cluster_name`. I needed to add a `depends_on` attribute to the `ecs_service`:

```
module "ecs_service" {
   source       = "app.terraform.io/ifit/ecs-service/aws"
   version      = "2.3.0"
   cluster_name = aws_ecs_cluster.cluster.name
   ...other stuff...
   depends_on  = [
     aws_ecs_cluster.cluster
   ]
}
```